# Uncaught ReferenceError: Persona is not defined en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, clase, frontend

lo que pasa es que estoy realizando un proyecto de mostrar un listado de personas en HTML y JS. Como primer paso, quiero mostrar dicho listado por medio de la consola para ir testeando y luego hacerlo visible en la página (para saber si está todo ok), sin embargo, al momento de mostrarlo en consola me sale el error de: Uncaught ReferenceError: Persona is not defined en JavaScript.

Me parece extraño, ya que tengo definida una clase persona y otro archivo js donde estoy declarando las funciones y no logró visualizar cual es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Listado de Personas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body onload="mostrarPersonas()">
    <div class="contenedor" id="cabecero">
        <h1>Listado de Personas</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="elemento">
            <ul id="personas">
                <!--<li>Juan Perez</li>-->

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/persona.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
const personas = [
    new Persona('Nicolas','Veloso'),
    new Persona('Francisco','Muñoz')
];

function mostrarPersonas(){
    console.log('mostrar personas');
    let texto = '';
    for(persona of personas){
        console.log(persona);
    }
}
```

persona.js

```
class Persona{
    constructor(nombre, apellido){
        this._nombre = nombre;
        this._apellido = apellido;
    }

    get nombre(){
        return this._nombre;
    }

    set nombre(nombre){
        this._nombre = nombre;
    }

    get apellido(){
        return this._apellido;
    }

    set apellido(apellido){
        this._apellido = apellido;
    }
}
```

Comment: Si app.js usa persona.js, debes poner el script de persona.js antes de app.js... por eso te dice que persona no está definido

Comment: @Pipe muchas gracias amigo! ahora si funciona.

Comment: Simplemente declara el script de persona.js antes que el de app.js